# workflow fails to send consecutive emails

Tags: sharepoint-online, email

I have a sharepoint2013 workflow that is supposed to send consecutive emails to 2 different recipients. whichever one I put first in the workflow it sends there but fails to fire the second one. what should I be doing to investigate

Comment: Take a screenshot of your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest breaking the emails into two nodes/actions first. If you've already done that, try sending the two emails within one node/action where they're separated by semicolons. Once you get it to send with the two emails within one node/action, then duplicate that node/action onto another branch and see if it sends.

If you have specific conditions setup for when the emails should be sent, then you may need to review if those conditions are met and the nodes/actions that follow are executed.

If you have more detailed information on how your workflow is setup, including the conditions and parameters, that may assist in determining where to investigate, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate following steps

- Send an email to both recipients one at a time to make sure both are valid email addresses.
- Put 2 email addresses in one email To and CC to see both are receiving at a time.
- Try type email addresses in TO field, if you are selecting emails from the people picker.
- If any one of emails are failed to receive see these accounts as a contacts or accounts in your tenant.
- See workflow history to see any reason for failure.